# This JS function works well, but when adding as a new String method with prototype, fails...

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have this code, and a bit of a beginner's problem:

```
function findfruit (food){

var fruitvalues = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "mango", "kiwi", "watermelon"];
if (fruitsvalues.indexOf(food) != -1){
    return true;
    }
else {
    return false;
    }
    }


var food = prompt("Write down any food you like");
findfruit(food) // returns always the correct answer, true or false
```

So here is the thing: This works well without problems, but if I do:

```
String.prototype.fruit = findfruit;
```

and then I try to make

```
if (food.fruit != true) {
    alert("your food is not a fruit");
    }
else {
    alert("your food is a fruit");
```

it doesn't work, and it always results "false". I suspect that my problem is that when I invoke `food.fruit`, the function `findfruit`starts without using the string variable `food`that I just created, but I don't understand why. I am just reading tutorials as for how to use `prototype`, and I cannot find anything wrong (although I am sure there is something).

I would appreciate any help. I know this must be pretty easy, but the other questions about prototype that I found here couldn't help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply use this to reference the string, you'll actually be scoped to the function. this.valueOf will look to the parent object (String).

```
String.prototype.fruit = function () {
var fruitvalues = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "mango", "kiwi", "watermelon"];
if (fruitvalues.indexOf(this.valueOf()) != -1){
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}

var food = 'apple';

if (food.fruit() != true) {
    console.log("your food is not a fruit");
}
else {
    console.log("your food is a fruit");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Writing `food.fruit` is not a function invocation. It will just return the function itself (which obviously can't be equal to true).

2) You can access the object from which the function is invoked as `this`. It won't be passed as an argument to your function (this isn't Python). The correct implementation is

```
String.prototype.fruit = function() {
   var fruitvalues = ["apple", "orange", "banana"];
   return (fruitvalues.indexOf(this.toString()) != -1);
}
```

3) Adding functions like this to prototypes of built-in types is discouraged. It's tempting, but you have to ask yourself: "Is this generic enough that I will need it everywhere in my program ?".

Comment: This would need `"use strict";` or `.indexOf(this + "")` to get a primitive value.

Comment: `indexOf(this)` will not work, you will always get false. You need to do `indexOf(this.toString())` or valueOf

Comment: Oh, I have read quite a lot about how discouraged is to use prototypes, but before I decide "not" to use it, I would like to learn the proper way to use it. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @pimvdb: Thanks, I forgot about that. Fixed now.